# Adding a label and path to a chart D3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I hope you can help. I am building a bar chart with D3 that I need to add labels to as well as append a path to show trends and goals. I added a line for the path but it doesn't seem to be generating. My CSV file with the data is structured like so:

```
date,projectCode,numberOfSchools,newSchools
2011-12-1,"PRJ2.1",1188,0
```

And code is below:

```
<!Doctype  html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>D3 bar and line chart for Aphellion</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.v3.js"></script>
            <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src"//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.8/d3.min.js"></script> -->
            <style type="text/css">
                /* the style for the page and charts goes here */
                .axis {
                    font: 10px sans-serif;
                }

                .axis path
                .axis line {
                    fill: none;
                    stroke: #000;
                    shape-rendering: crispEdges;

                }

                .rect:hover {
                fill: orange;
            }

            #tooltip {
                background-color: white;
                -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
                -moz-border-radius: 10px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
                -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
                box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
                pointer-events: none;
            }

            #tooltip.hidden {
                display: none;
            }

            #tooltip p {
                margin: 0;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 16px;
                line-height: 20px;
            }
            </style>

        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="lineChart"></div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            "Use strict"

                //The script for the bar chart and line charts goes here
                var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
                    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
                    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom
                    barPadding = 3;

                //parse the date / time
                var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

                //set up the scales
                var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

                var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]); 

                //set up the axis
                var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                            .scale(x)
                            .orient("bottom")
                            .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m"));

                var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                            .scale(y)
                            .orient("left")
                            .ticks(5);

                var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                .attr("class", "barChart")
                                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                            .append("g")
                                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

                d3.csv("Data/data.csv", function(error, data) {
                        data.forEach(function(d) {
                            d.date = parseDate(d.date.toString());
                            d.numberOfSchools = +d.numberOfSchools;
                        });

                        x.domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.date;}));
                        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.numberOfSchools;})]);


                        svg.append("g")
                            .attr("class", "x axis")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                            .call(xAxis)
                        .selectAll("text")
                            .style("text-anchor", "end")
                            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                            .attr("dy", "-.55em")
                            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

                        svg.append("g")
                            .attr("class", "y axis")
                            .call(yAxis)
                        .append("text")
                            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                            .attr("y", 6)
                            .attr("dy", ".71em")
                            .style("text-anchor", "end")
                            .text("Schools");

                        svg.selectAll("bar")
                            .data(data)
                            .enter()
                            .append("rect")
                            .style("fill", function(d) {
                                if(d.numberOfSchools < 1200) {
                                    return "#ff0000";
                                } else if (d.numberOfSchools === 2000) {
                                    return "#33cc33";
                                } else {return "steelblue";}
                            })
                            .attr("class", "rect")
                            .attr("x", function(d) {return x(d.date);})
                            .attr("width", x.rangeBand() - barPadding)
                            .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.numberOfSchools);})
                            .attr("height", function(d) {return height - y(d.numberOfSchools);})
                            .on("mouseover", function(d) {

                            //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
                            var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x")) + x.rangeBand() / 2;
                            var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) + 14;

                            //Create the tooltip label
                            svg.append("text")
                                .attr("id", "tooltip")
                                .attr("x", xPosition)
                                .attr("y", yPosition)
                                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                                .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                                .attr("font-size", "11px")
                                .attr("font-weight", "bold")
                                .attr("fill", "black")
                                .text(d.numberOfSchools + " current schools.");

                                })
                            .on("mouseout", function() {

                            //Remove the tooltip
                            d3.select("#tooltip").remove();

                            });

                            svg.selectAll("text")
                                .data(data)
                                .enter()
                                .append("text")
                                .text(function(d) {
                                    return d.numberOfSchools;
                                })
                                .attr("x", function(d) {return x(d.date);})
                                .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.numberOfSchools);});
             })


                //add a path to interpolate through the bars
                var line = d3.svg.line()
                            .x(function(d) {return x(d.date)})
                            .y(function(d) {return y(d.numberOfSchools)});

                //add the path
                /*d3.select("svg")
                    .append("path")
                        .attr("d", line(data.numberOfSchools))
                        .attr("class", "numberOfSchools");
                });*/



                    console.log("This code works");


            </script>
        </body>


    </html>
```

Also theoretically can I use the same code to create a line chart with the bars? I tried creating a fiddle but my CSV can't be added. Here it is though: http://jsfiddle.net/siyafrica/bfVHU/

Comment: have a look at this http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-simple-line-bar-charts-using-d3-js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

## jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/reblace/bfVHU/7/

I had to make a bunch of changes to get it working, but basically it's hard to get the rangeBands method working with bar charts using time data. There's a bunch of stuff written on this subject, here's a good (brief) convo about it: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/7GsDmnB4kdE

I switched it to use a date scale, which will generally work, but you'll have to do some work to get the bar widths and positioning to be correct.

```
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
```

Also, your line generator needs to be passed the data array...

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {return x(d.date)})
    .y(function(d) {return y(d.value)});

//add the path
svg.append("path")
    .attr("d", line(data))
    .attr("class", "numberOfSchools");
```

If you want to stick with the ordinal x scale and use rangebands, you may need a secondary time scale for drawing the path and you will want to add all the dates in the extent of the domain, otherwise "empty" days will not show up on your chart.